# Generating random unique BigIntegers within a specified range?

Tags: java, biginteger

I'm new to using BigInteger, so I'm trying my best reading through the documentation for it. I'm still confused however. I need to generate 500 random integers between the range of 2^70 and 2^80 and I don't know how to set a range for BigIntegers.

I'm getting the possible duplicate messages, so I guess I should add that I've already looked at the solutions in this one and still don't understand how to solve my issue: [How to generate a random BigInteger value in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290057/how-to-generate-a-random-biginteger-value-in-java)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate a random BigInteger value in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290057/how-to-generate-a-random-biginteger-value-in-java)
I think that question should answer yours.

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290057/how-to-generate-a-random-biginteger-value-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [built-in method to generate a random BigInteger](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger%28int,%20java.util.Random%29) between 0 and 2^n - 1.

You can use that in a loop to generate numbers up to 2^80.

The chance that a number will fall below 2^70 is very small ( ~ 0.1%). If that happens (and with 500 iterations it might very well), just draw another one.

This will give you a uniform distribution of random numbers between 2^70 and 2^80.

The chance that a number will repeat is almost nonexistent. If you feel that it cannot be ignored, check your previous numbers for duplicates, and draw again.

Comment: Is it possible to set the minimum range value though? For the case of my assignment, it needs to be set within that specific range.

Comment: What is the minimum range? If it is 2^70, the above will work very well. If it is 2^78, better use a different method, such as http://stackoverflow.com/a/23054579/14955.